# How to get list1 items that any items of sublist1 at least has one item of list2?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of users which each user has some favorite products. so each user has a list of favorite products.

in a search panel i want to check some products and as a search result I want to return list of users that at least has one of those checked product. at least one. but not users that didn't check any of those products.

```
    public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<UserProduct> UserProducts { get; set; }

    public User()
    {

    }

    public User(long id,string name,List<long> productIds)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        UserProducts = productIds.Select(x => new UserProduct(id, x)).ToList();
    }
}

public class Products
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public Products()
    {

    }

    public Products(int productId,string name)
    {
        ProductId = productId;
        ProductName = name;
    }


}

public class UserProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    public UserProduct()
    {

    }

    public UserProduct(long userId,long productId)
    {
        ProductId = productId;
        UserId = userId;
    }
}

public class SearchDto
{
    public List<long> SearchProductIds { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public void FillUsers()
    {
        List<Products> products=new List<Products>()
        {
            new Products(1,"a"),
            new Products(2,"b"),
            new Products(3,"c"),
            new Products(4,"d"),
            new Products(5,"e"),
            new Products(6,"f"),
            new Products(7,"g"),
        };
        List<User> users=new    List<User>()
        {
            new User(1,"jack",new List<long>(){1} ),
            new User(2,"Mary",new List<long>(){1,4} ),
            new User(3,"Sam",new List<long>(){5} ),
            new User(4,"Sara",new List<long>(){7,1,2} ),
        };

        SearchDto dto=new SearchDto()
        {
            SearchProductIds = new List<long> { 1,4}
        };


        //Here as search dto :I want to get Jack,Mary and Sara  beacause they have 1 or 4 in their products
    }
}
```

Comment: dont forget the model, it would be best to see the classes

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a list of IDs of the products that you selected(`selectedProductIdList`)

I am assuming that your 
`User` Model looks like this

```
public string Username {get; set;}
public string FirstName {get; set;}
//....
//more User data
//....
public List<Product> FavouriteProduct {get; set;}
```

Your user search result would be

```
var userList = listOfUsers.Where(u => u.FavouriteProduct.Where(p => selectedProductIdList.Contains(p.Id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the lists are in memory, in case of database modify code accordingly.

```
var result= (from p1 in SearchDtoList
             join p2 in UserProductList
             on p1 equals p2.ProductId 
             join u in UserList
             on p2.UserId equals u.Id
             select u).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If  SearchPanelDto.SelectedProductsList returns list of Ids then

```
    Var searchedProductsIds = SearchPanelDto.SelectedProductsList;  

    var userList = listOfUsers.Where(m =>
                        searchedProductsIds.Any(x=> m.IntrestetProducts.Select(t => t.ProductId).Any(z => x.Equals(z))));
```

else if SearchPanelDto.SelectedProductsList return list of object which contains Id

```
    //Get selected productIds from search panel
    Var searchedProductsIds = SearchPanelDto.SelectedProductsList.select(m=>m.ProductId).ToList();

    var userList = listOfUsers.Where(m =>
                        searchedProductsIds.Any(x=> m.IntrestetProducts.Select(t => t.ProductId).Any(z => x.Equals(z))));
```